# startForeground not showing notification again

Tags: java, android, service, notifications, android-7.0-nougat

In my foreground service the code for starting service is as follows:

```
 notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)  // the status icon
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())  // the time stamp
                .setCustomContentView(getSmallContentView())
                .setCustomBigContentView(getBigContentView())
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setOngoing(true);
        if (Build.VERSION_CODES.O <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelId, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        // Send the notification.
        startForeground(notificationId, notification);
```

Calling `stopForeground(true)` and after that calling `startForeground(id,notification)` does not show notification again in foreground service.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `In my foreground service the code for starting service is as follows:`. That looks more like code that creates a notification.

Comment: @greenapps   startForeground(notificationId, notification); - It starts service in foreground.

Comment: If you omit that statement the service is still started. So what it does is creating a notification. With implications.